# Python Graphviz/Dot: Warning: node File, port port unrecognized

Tags: python, graph, graphviz

- Is there such a code that produces a picture with the following coordinates:

```
    import gvfrom pygraph.classes.graph import graph
    from pygraph.classes.digraph import digraph
    from pygraph.algorithms.searching import breadth_first_search
    from pygraph.readwrite.dot import write

    gr = graph()

    pass

    gr.add_nodes(["HOST(name)", "REDIS", "MEMCACHED", "File:port", "HOST(other-name)"])

    gr.add_edge(("HOST(name)", "REDIS"))
    gr.add_edge(("HOST(name)", "MEMCACHED"))
    gr.add_edge(("HOST(name)", "File:port" ))
    gr.add_edge(("HOST(other-name)", "File:port"))

    dot = write(gr)
    gvv = gv.readstring(dot)
    gv.layout(gvv, "dot")gv.render(gvv, "png", "test.png")
```

- He even runs, BUT I don't like the fact that he returns after the execution, except for the still pictures and warnings

  `Warning: node File, port port unrecognized`

  `Warning: node File, port port unrecognized`
- Like as valid but incorrect syntax of the transfer function.
  Help me to understand.

Comment: Just a guess, but you might not be able to use colons `:` in your node names. Have you tried replacing them with something like hyphens `-` ?

Comment: Yepp, i'm tried ":" -> "-", but me need ":"

Answer (score 0):

try saving as SVG with

```
"File&#58;Port"
```

to avoid the error about unrecognised ports and display the colon as an HTML character

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a problem with punctuation characters.  I ran into the same problem with literal ampersands in text strings.  I had to do the following to all the strings to "sanitize" them:

```
  textString.replace("&", "&amp;")
```

With that, the strings would render properly, and graphviz would not try to parse the ampersands.  Will probably work for colon (like @snow6oy's answer) and other punctuation characters too.